# PHP Преобразование и приведение к целому

Tags: php, преобразование, типы

Может подскажет кто почему числа с плавающей 410 и 510 приводятся и преобразовываются к целочисленному типу как 409 и 509 соответственно. Может правда и еще какие то, но эти точно.

Как вообще с этим можно бороться?

UPD:

```
$amount = 5.1;
$stemp = $amount*100;
echo (int)$stemp; //509
```

Если `$amount = 6.1`, то все ожидаемо: выводит 610. Непонятная ситуация наблюдается только при 4.1 и 5.1

PHP 5.5.9

Comment: ЧЯДНТ? `var_dump(intval(410.2332)); //410` ?

Comment: @ИванПшеницын, var_dump(intval(409.999)); //409 :Р

Comment: Приведите контекст исполнения

Comment: Да, безобразие! Теперь озвучьте что именно за безобразие, оформленное в виде кода-примера, чтобы можно петицию разработчикам `PHP` отправить.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын  |
`echo var_dump(intval($stemp)); //int(509) ` |
`echo var_dump($stemp); //float(510)`

Comment: @ЕвгенийКудряшов `var_dump(409.999999999999); //float(410)` но разумеется  `var_dump(intval(409.999999999999)); //10`. собственно, аналогично `var_dump(intval(329.99999999999999)); //float(330)` ничего удивительного. вы код свой приведите лучше, кто знает, что у вас там в переменных.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын всмысле ничего удивительного? что из 510 получается 509, неудивительно? :/
`$amount = (float)$_GET["amount"];
$stemp = $amount*100;
echo (int)$stemp; // при amount = 5.1 возвращает 509`

Comment: @ЕвгенийКудряшов вы раз за разом показываете переменные. Что в них - не до конца ясно. Я вам продемонстрировал ситуацию, при которой из 409.999999999999 получается целочисленное 409 (естественно) и floаt(410) (ничего удивительного: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.float.php). Прочитайте про точность чисел.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын  `$amount = (float)$_GET["amount"];
$stemp = $amount*100;
echo (int)$stemp; // при amount = 5.1 возвращает 509`
Я не против что я могу ошибатся.. Но либо у меня проблеммы с логикой. При значения 6.1, 7.1 и многих прочих - все нормально. У меня такое получается только при 4.1 и 5.1.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКудряшов, у вас не проблема с логикой, это у компьютеров проблема с математикой. У них она дискретная!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выдержка из [мануалов](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.float.php):

> **Точность чисел с плавающей точкой**
>
> Числа с плавающей точкой имеют ограниченную точность. Хотя это зависит
>   от операционной системы, в PHP обычно используется формат двойной
>   точности IEEE 754, дающий максимальную относительную ошибку округления
>   порядка 1.11e-16. Неэлементарные арифметические операции могут давать
>   большие ошибки, и, разумеется, необходимо принимать во внимание
>   распространение ошибок при совместном использовании нескольких
>   операций.
>
> **Кроме того, рациональные числа, которые могут быть точно представлены
>   в виде чисел с плавающей точкой с основанием 10, например, 0.1 или
>   0.7, не имеют точного внутреннего представления в качестве чисел с плавающей точкой с основанием 2, вне зависимости от размера мантиссы.**
>   Поэтому они и не могут быть преобразованы в их внутреннюю двоичную
>   форму без небольшой потери точности. Это может привести к неожиданным
>   результатам: например, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) скорее всего вернет 7
>   вместо ожидаемого 8, так как результат внутреннего представления будет
>   чем-то вроде 7.9999999999999991118....
>
> **Так что никогда не доверяйте точности чисел с плавающей точкой до
>   последней цифры**, и не проверяйте напрямую их равенство. Если вам
>   действительно необходима высокая точность, [используйте математические
>   функции произвольной точности](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.bc.php) и [gmp-функции](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.gmp.php).

Решение вашей проблемы:

```
<?php

$x = 5.1;
$y = 100;
$z = (int) bcmul((string) $x, (string) $y);

echo '<pre>'."\n";
var_dump($z); // int(510)
echo '</pre>'."\n";
```

Comment: Спасибо, это должно помочь.

Answer (score 0):

все дело в точности числа с плавающей запятой

источник, а там и варианты решения http://www.php.su/learnphp/datatypes/?float#erc

Answer (score 0):

Эта погрешность действительно присутствует в php, можно побороть функцией `round` :

```
$d["amount"] = 5.1;

$amount = (float)$d["amount"]; 

$stemp = $amount*100; 

var_dump((int) round($stemp, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP)); //ш510
```