# Дробная часть и sprintf

Tags: php

Привет, подскажите, почему в sprintf 42 превращается в 41

```
$time = 7.42;
$mnt = fmod($time, 1) * 100;
//$mnt = ($time - floor($time)) * 100 ;
//$mnt = 0.42*100;
echo $mnt;
echo "<br>";
echo sprintf("%0dhr %02dm", (int) $time, $mnt);

// 42
// 7hr 41m
```

Comment: при каком условии? Сейчас твой код не отображает её вообще

Comment: @iormark, ответ тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/553556/186083 Тест тут http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fc98ecb997e39a828cc2a2b038ed32f199c8eede

Comment: @Visman благодарю. 
echo sprintf("%0shr %02sm", (int) $time, $mnt);

Comment: Да, хитрый план с переводом в строку тоже работает: `$mnt = (string) fmod($time, 1) * 100;` :)

Comment: @ Visman не, не вариант: 10.05 => 5.0000000000001, хооотяяяя с number_format($mnt, 0)